# Overlay permission on instant app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, overlay, android-instant-apps

I am trying to use a "Floating Widget" triggered from an instant app, in order to do so I need get the `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` that I should be able to get this way :

```
intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
               Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivityForResult(intent, APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
```

Unfortunatly I get this runtime error when I try to start this Intent :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.instantapps.samples.hellofeature/com.instantappsamples.feature.hello.HelloActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION dat=package:com.google.android.instantapps.samples.hellofeature }
```

Could it be possible that this right can not be obtained from an instant app ?
(The installed app is working fine )

Comment: can you simply try `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION))` ?

Comment: If does not work either :

    Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION }

Comment: Which OS version and device are you using for these test?

Comment: the tests are running on Nexus 6p and Pixel Simulators (since my phone does not support instant app for unknown reasons) from api 24 to 27

Comment: Can you try this, its working for me on N `Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivity(intent);`

Comment: It does not work.... Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION dat=package:com.google.android.instantapps.samples.hellofeature }


Are you using Instant app ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instant Apps have a limited view of PackageManager. I don't have a good reference handy to say for sure that Settings - or this activity in particular - are not visible. But the expectation should be that most activities in most packages are not visible.

Even if you were able to get to this activity (or, if you just go there as a user, by navigating to it in the Settings app), your instant app isn't going to be allowed to get this permission. Both for technical reasons (because PackageManager generally doesn't know about instant apps, at least in pre-O versions), and by policy. Specifically, overlay would imply some level of background operation, which is disallowed per the [FAQ](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs). (Also note that overlay is not listed in that page's list of allowed permissions.)